# How to pass an entire object in a multitraded program

Tags: python, multithreading, events, python-multithreading

I'm started a concurrent program using Python. I have a simple question:
I'm using the class Thread to create several concurrent processes.
I would like these threads to pass objects to each other (so I would like that a thread not only notice a certain event, but takes an object from this event (when it happens)!).
How can I do this? Thanks a lot!

Example of code:

```
class Process(Thread):
def __init__(self):
    super(Processo, self).__init__()

def run(self):
    myObject = SomeObject(param1, param2, param3)
    # Code to pass myObject to all the threads

    # Code waiting for the object to use it

def main():
   process1 = Process()
   process2 = Process()
   process3 = Process()

   process1.start()
   process2.start()
   process3.start()
```

Comment: Please provide some code and then I might be able to help you with this.

Comment: Code added to the answer....

Comment: Add `global myObject` and all your `Thread`'s can access this object. You have to use [lock-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) if concurent `read/write` could be the case. BTW, a `Thread` **is not** a `Process`,  read [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

Comment: Use `queue.Queue` [Queue docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queue.Queue` to communicate between threads. There is simple example of two threads. One thread puts items on the one side of the `queue` and the other take them. The `queue` can be also used for multi-producer multi-consumer application (but before implementing plan how it should work).

```
from queue import Queue
from random import randint
import threading 
import time

class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Producer, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            thread_name = self.name

            if not self.queue.full():
                print('Will send "{}"'.format(thread_name))
                self.queue.put(thread_name)

            time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Consumer, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.queue.empty():
                received = self.queue.get()
                print('Received "{}"'.format(received))

            time.sleep(randint(1, 3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()

    a = Producer(queue=q)
    b = Consumer(queue=q)

    a.start()
    b.start()

    a.join()
    b.join()
```

The `sleeps` are only to slow it down for demonstration. There is documentation for [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

*Note: Thread is not the same as a Process. Be careful with terminology you can be miss-understood.*